# Problems getting data from database using stored procedure

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm new here but I follow the community since some years and I've always found what I was looking for. Now I have a specific request I searched here and on the web but I haven't found any answer, hope somebody here can help me.

I am using this stored procedure to fetch data from a SQL Server database:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Lots_GetLotsData
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT * FROM Lots
```

and this one to update only one item of the table

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Lots_CloseLot
(
    @Lot_Code varchar(12)
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE [Lots] SET [Closed] = 1
    WHERE [LotCode] = @Lot_Code
```

In my c# program, I am using a Linq-to-SQL datacontext where I put all the stored procedure I call. In the code, I call the "Lots_CloseLot" stored procedure and it's executed correctly, but when I call the "Lots_GetLotsData" stored procedure, I get the old values (even if looking into the database the data has been updated). If I close and start again my application I get the correct result.

If U call the stored procedures from VS or SSMS I get the correct result (especially the "GetLotsData" stored procedure).

Can anybody help me find where is the mistake?

Thanks in advance

[EDIT]

I tried to recreate the connection after calling the "CloseLot" stored procedure and it works, it seems that the connection breaks for some reason. The strange thing is that if I don't recreate the connection the "GetLotsData" procedure is not working correctly after calling the "CloseLot" procedure, but I can add data and I can get the new data I added. If the right way to solve is to recreate the connection it's ok, but I would like to understand where the problem is and, if possible, to solve it.

Comment: Your connection statement is probably incorrect and you are connecting to the wrong database file.

Comment: It seems strange since I can run all the stored procedures. How can I check if the connection is correct or not?

Comment: You may be connected to a temporary file and not the actual database.  You should NOT use the mdf filename.  You should connect to the server and use the database name in the server.  The server name should be the same as in the SSMS login window.  The database name is in the SSMS explorer under Databases.  See www.connectionstrings.com.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for my late one, I was out of the office. I connect to the SQL server using this connection string: "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LotDBase;Integrated Security=True" and I've always used this connection string (changing database's name) and I've never connected to a mdf file.

Comment: Try adding a Use DATABASE_NAME statement to the stored procedure.  It should be using the Initial Catalog for the default USE but maybe it is not working properly.  You can log into database using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to verify data.  You may have more than one database or somehow accessing wrong table.  Also check that the two stored procedures are store in SQL in same location.